# Resource bounded Kolmogorov complexity hardness on average over a non uniform distribution of inputs

Tags: turing-machines, polynomial-time, kolmogorov-complexity

$K^{poly}$, as well as other related problems such as $MCSP$, is believed to be hard on average [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.11514), [2](https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10351107)] when the input is sampled from a **uniform distribution** (since otherwise one way functions, pseudo-randomness, cryptography, etc. would not exist).
What do we know about **other distributions**?
Let say that the inputs $x$ of length $n$ are sampled from some distribution $\mathcal{D}_n$ over $\{0, 1\}^n$:

- For $x \sim \mathcal{U_n}$, with $\mathcal{U_n}$ the uniform distribution, computing $K^{poly}(x)$ is believed to be hard on average.
- For $x \sim \mathcal{Dummy}$, with $\mathcal{Dummy}$ a distribution that output a simple string (such as "0") most of the time, computing $K^{poly}$ is obviously easy on average.

Is there any interesting case in between those two?
i.e. is there any interesting distribution $x \sim \mathcal{D}_n$ for which $K^{poly}(x)$ is somewhat easy on average?

For example, what if $x$ follows the (resource bounded version of) Levin's Universal distribution?
Or what if $x$ is sampled in the following manner:

1. $p \sim \mathcal{U_n}$ : uniformly sample a program $p$.
2. $x = M(p)$ : compute $x$ using a (resource bounded) Turing Machine $M$ to evaluate $p$.

I understand that in the cryptography or meta complexity settings, the uniform case is more interesting, but it seems to me that for learning we don't really care about uniformly random inputs.

1. [Liu, Y., & Pass, R. (2020). On One-way Functions and Kolmogorov Complexity. 2020 IEEE 61st Annual Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science (FOCS), 1243-1254.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.11514)
2. [Allender, E. (2021). Vaughan Jones, Kolmogorov Complexity, and the New Complexity Landscape around Circuit Minimization. New Zealand Journal of Mathematics.](https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10351107)